# Pass variable number of arguments received to another function

Tags: c, function, arguments, ansi-c

Before you say it's duplicated, I already read this: [How to pass variable number of arguments from one function to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672753/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-from-one-function-to-another)

I have a function like this:

```
void tlog_function(t_log* logger, const char* message_template, ...) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&loggerLock);
    log_function(logger, message_template, ...); // What I want to do..
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&loggerLock);
}
```

And another function like this, which is not mine, I use it from a third-party library:

```
void log_function(t_log* logger, const char* message_template, ...);
```

As you can see, what I want to do is just add a mutex to this function to make it thread-safe, I know I can use `va_list` but in this case I cannot change the code of the second function, because it is inside a library and I only have the .h file.

So, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any equivalent function `log_function(t_log* logger, const char* message_template, va_list args);`?

Comment: @iharob No, there's not :(

Comment: I don't think it's possible then.

Comment: @iharob So what would you do I you have to make a function like this to be thread-safe?

Comment: What does the `log_function()` do?

Comment: Outside of using a VA_ARGS-based macro, this isn't likely to happen if there is no `va_list` version of that function.

Comment: It logs the string to a file and also the console, but the string gets formatted. i.e. `log_function(mdfs_logger, "this is a message with a string %s and a number %d ", "str", 5);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you cannot change the code and there is no `va_list` version of the library function you can use the closest thing I am aware of is to use a macro and [`##__VA_ARGS__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) ([which is a GCC only extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588855/standard-alternative-to-gccs-va-args-trick)).

You will want something like this:

```
#define tlog_function(logger, message_template, ...) do { \
    pthread_mutex_lock(&loggerLock);                                         \
    log_function(logger, message_template, ##__VA_ARGS__);                   \
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&loggerLock);                                       \
} while(0)
```

Comment: FYI, it's only the `, ## __VA_ARGS__` construct to permit passing *zero* variable arguments that is a GCC extension.  `__VA_ARGS__` itself is standard C99.

Comment: @zwol thanks for the catch I have updated my answer to be more specific.

Comment: It worked! I just removed the types of the first two arguments as they are not needed and also there can't be a pointer. Thanks !!

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez thanks for that catch about the types and I'm glad it worked.

Comment: @esm Also, why do you use `do while`? I just removed that and worked fine ! Is there any reason?

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez It's a common trick to allow you to use your macro with if.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257418/do-while-0-what-is-it-good-for

Answer (score 2):

You cannot write a function that forwards its variable argument list to another variadic function with the facilities provided by standard C.  Indeed, `vfprintf` exists precisely because this is not possible.  (As discussed in esm's answer, a *macro* can do this.)

If additional third-party libraries are an option, [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) may be persuadable to do what you want.  (How does libffi work, you ask?  [Hand-written assembly language](https://github.com/atgreen/libffi/blob/master/src/x86/sysv.S).)